# How to solve the following differential equation: $(2x^3-x^2-y)dx-(2x^2y-x)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like your help with this differential equation:
$(2x^3-x^2-y)dx-(2x^2y-x)dy=0$

It seems not difficult, but I have no idea about it

Thanks a lot for help)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please provide us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you studied differential equations? Have you solved any DE like this before? Do you have access to a DE textbook? The answers to these question can provide needed context for your question here.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/differential-equations-exact-factors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Divide the equation by $x^2$ to get$$(2x-1)dx-2ydy+\left(\frac{dy}x-\frac{ydx}{x^2}\right)=0$$The last term is an exact differential, $d(y/x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2x^3-x^2-y)dx-(2x^2y-x)dy=0$$
If you rearrange terms the DE becomes:
$$x^2(2x-1)dx+(xdy-ydx)-x^2(2ydy)=0$$
$$(2x-1)dx+d\left (\dfrac yx \right) -dy^2=0$$
Integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Seek a total derivative $df=0$ by multiplying by an Ansatz $x^ay^b$ viz.$$f_x=2x^{a+3}y^b-x^{a+2}y^b-x^ay^{b+1},\,f_y=x^{a+1}y^b-2x^{a+2}y^{b+1}$$so$$0=\frac{f_{xy}-f_{yx}}{x^{a-1}y^{b-1}}=2bx^4-bx^3-(a+b+2)xy+2(a+2)x^2y^2.$$Equating coefficients gives $a=-2,\,b=0$, so$$df=(2x-1-y/x^2)dx+(1/x-2y)dy\implies f=x^2-x+y/x-y^2-C.$$The constraint therefore reduces to $x^2-x+y/x-y^2=C$.